# How many tamids on Rosh Hashana?

Tags: korban, rosh-hashanah-new-year, musaf, nusach-sefard

In the *musaf* prayer on Rosh Hashana, we list the *musaf* offerings that they used to bring in the Temple in Jerusalem (and that we hope to bring again soon), special for Rosh Hashana. The text then lists other things brought, too:

> ‏…ושני שעירים לכפר ושני תמידים כהלכתם, מלבד עלת החדש ומנחתה ועלת התמיד ומנחתה…‏
>
> …and two goats to atone and two daily-offerings according to their rule, besides the monthly wholly-offered offering and its meal, and the daily wholly-offered offering and its meal…

Why does it mention the daily offering (תמיד) twice?

Comment: Probably someone had the idea to add the verse in later, and no one bothered to remove the now superfluous ושני תמידים כהלכתם

Comment: And a third Tamid when it's also Shabbat: על עלת התמיד ונסכה